# How can I fetch StoreId data from aspnetusers table in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, c#-6.0

Actually I want to check if current `StoreId` and user's `StoreId` is same or not. If same then I want to authenticate. How can I do that?

ASPNETUSERS Table-

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[UserName]
      ,[NormalizedUserName]
      ,[Email]
      ,[NormalizedEmail]
      ,[EmailConfirmed]
      ,[PasswordHash]
      ,[SecurityStamp]
      ,[ConcurrencyStamp]
      ,[PhoneNumber]
      ,[PhoneNumberConfirmed]
      ,[TwoFactorEnabled]
      ,[LockoutEnd]
      ,[LockoutEnabled]
      ,[AccessFailedCount]
      ,[StoreId]
  FROM [EcommerceDb].[dbo].[AspNetUsers]
```

ShopController `Login` Method:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    model.ReturnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/Customer/Shop/");

    model.ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(model.ReturnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = model.ReturnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

`Login` Model:

```cs
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme>? ExternalLogins { get; set; }
    public string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string? StoreId { get; set; }
}
```

`Login` Form:

```cs
<form asp-area="Customer" asp-controller="Shop" asp-action="Login" class="ogani_registerForm" id="account" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6 d-block">
            <input asp-for="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>

            <input asp-for="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="StoreId" id="StoreId" name="StoreId" value="@Model.StoreId" aria-required="true">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="site-btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between my-5">
                <a class="forgot_password" asp-area="Customer" asp-controller="Shop" asp-action="Register" 
                asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl"><i class="fa fa-user-plus pr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    Don't have an account? Register Now!                            
                </a>
                <a id="forgot-password" asp-area="Customer" asp-controller="Shop" asp-action="ForgotPassword" 
                class="forgot_password">Forgot Password 
                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right pl-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>                        
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your current `StoreId`? We usually say current xxx in Identity means current user's xxx. Do you mean you want to compare with the `StoreId` from the database of current user and the `StoreId` you form submit?

Comment: How is the StoreId being populated?

Comment: I got the solution  => `var userStoreId = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userEmail).Result.StoreId;`